# Trying to create a matrix plot, but something is wrong

Tags: c++

Now, the main goal of the program is to create a 121x61 matrix, reset it, and draw two lines which represent the plot plane. However, this program for some reason does create the plot for the y line, but it somehow copies it a few positions in the matrix, again (It skips one value though). The plot has to be drawn by replacing the 0s with 1s.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define rd 57.2957795
#define k 0.05
using namespace std;
void rmat(int matrix[121][61])
{
    for (int i=0;i<121;i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<61;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
void matrix_print(int matrix[121][61])
{
    for( int y = 0; y < 61 ; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < 121; x++ )
        {
            cout << matrix[y][x];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
void mplot(int matrix[121][61])
{
    for( int y = 0; y < 61 ; y++ )
        matrix[y][0] = 1;
}
int main(void)
{
    int matrix[121][61];
    int i,x=0;
    double y = 0;
    double temp;

    rmat(matrix);
    system("mode con: cols=200 lines=200");
     /* for( x ; x < 180 ; x = x + 4 )
    {
        temp = cos(double(x) / rd);

    }
*/
    mplot(matrix);
    matrix_print(matrix);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your matrix indices the wrong way round in several places: the first index runs from 0 to 120 and the second runs from 0 to 60, not the other way around.

Here is an example of one such mistake:

```
for( int y = 0; y < 61 ; y++ )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < 121; x++ )
    {
        cout << matrix[y][x];
```

Comment: It's meant to be so, in order to print the matrix horizontally.